# Dynamic Binding in Java with subclasses

Tags: java

```java
interface  I {
    public  void m1();
    public  void m3();
 }
 class A implements I {
    public void m1() {
       System.out.println("A.m1");
       this.m2(this);
    }
    public void m2(I obj) {
       System.out.println("A.m2");
       obj.m3();
    }
    public void m3() {
       System.out.println("A.m3");
    }
 }
 public class B extends A {
    public void m2(I obj) {
       System.out.println("B.m2");
       super.m2(obj);
    }
    public void m3() {
       System.out.println("B.m3");
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
      I obj = new B();
      obj.m1();
    }
 }
```

When calling a method, the java compiler firstly checks if the apparent type of the obj has such method(in this case, it checks if the Interface I has the method m1() ) and then checks the actual type for the actual method call(and thus it calls the A's m1() method since the class B doesnt have it ).
However, why doesnt java compiler, when calling this.m2() inside A's m1() method, also checks if the Interface I has m2() method?
The output of this program is the following:

```
A.m1
B.m2
A.m2
B.m3
```

Comment: So `A` has `m2()` defined. But you're wondering why the compiler does not prevent a call to `m2()` on the grounds that `m2()` is not defined in the interface `I` implemented by `A`? What would be the reason for the compiler to demand a supertype's definition when the class itself has the method declared?

Comment: Oh, it makes sense, that was easier than expected. Thank you very much!!